# Laravel how to make on_or_after validation rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been following the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules) and a couple stackoverflow post but it seems I made a mistake I can't figure out. I get the the error `Method[validateOnOrAfter]` does not exist.

**app/start/global.php**

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/custom',
));
```

**app/custom/validation.php**

```
    <?php

    class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
    {

      public function validateOnOrAfter($attribute, $value, $parameters)
      {
        $OnOrAfter = strtotime($this->getValue($parameters[0]));
        $ToValidateDate = strtotime($value);

        return ($OnOrAfter >= $ToValidateDate);
      }

    }

    Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
      {
        $messages = array(
          'on_or_after' => 'The :attribute must be on of after :value'
        );

        return new CustomValidator(($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
      }
```

**Edit**
In desperation I also tried using the other method in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules) `Validator::extend` directly in the `controller@store` method (had to make some changes to code) and that **does** find the method but it does nothing in my validation despite the return value being false.

**app/controller/ProgramSession@store**

```
  Validator::extend( 'on_or_after', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
  {
    $OnOrAfterThisDate = Input::get($parameters[0]);
    $ToValidateDate = ($value);
//dd(strtotime($OnOrAfterThisDate) <= strtotime($ToValidateDate));

    return (strtotime($OnOrAfterThisDate) <= strtotime($ToValidateDate));
  });

Validator::replacer('on_or_after', function($message, $attribute, $rules, $parameters)
  {
    $messages = array(
      'on_or_after' => 'The :attribute must be on of after :parameter'
    );

  });
```